# Daylight saving not considered for timezone

Tags: java

I am getting the timezone using the timezone class

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Brisbane");
```

As far as I know, day light saving time is applicable for "Australia/Brisbane" timezone.

However what I found is that java does not consider daylight savings for this timezone.

I have tried running the timezone updater tool, but did not help.
Please let me know if anything additional needs to be done

Answer (score 4):

[Brisbane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisbane) (and its state, [Queensland](http://echo%20%22VIEW%20VXABC%22%20%7Csed%20%27s/VIEW%20V_?X/VIEW%20ABC/%27)) does **NOT** use daylight savings. Ever.

I know this with absolute certainty (I'm an Australian).

Answer (score 1):

The [`TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) class has a method called [`useDaylightTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#useDaylightTime%28%29), which 'queries if this timezone uses daylight savings time'.

Here is a quick program to tell you the answer:

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DaylightSavings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Brisbane");
        System.out.println(tz.useDaylightTime());
    }
}
```

Spoiler alert:  It prints `false`.